# Where is the documentation that states TCP and UDP source port should be over 1024 and random?

Tags: tcpip, udp, rfc

I am having a hard time to find where it is documented that the source port should be random and in the range 1024-65535.

In which RFC is this documented?

Edit:
First reference for privileged ports is in RFC2623
It seems that this is depending more on the TCP/IP implementation and it is a de-facto standard.

IANA is assigning the port numbers (RFC1700)

Comment: FYR - RFC 1700 (STD 2) only deals with the assignment of **listener** ports (where services listen for connections). It doesn't deal with the selection of the connecting server's source port.

Comment: Yes, but the corollary that you "SHOULD" use the registered ports is that you should not use them for other stuff. That is why I mentioned it.

Comment: http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xml talks about the Dynamic and/or Private
Ports (49152-65535). So it seems that the client should use a port from that range.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are probably looking for [RFC 6056](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6056) - Recommendations for Transport-Protocol Port Randomization
("Best Current Practice").

Technically there is no *requirement* that the ephemeral port be >1024 or random (you could build a system that always initiates connections from port 12 because you like the number 12), it's just not "normal" to do so (and an awful idea for a bunch of reasons, some of which are described in that RFC).

Comment: It looks that ephemeral ports should be >=49152. But your answer is the closest one to my question.

Answer (score 4):

The [RFC 6335](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6335) is explaining this:

> Ports in the Dynamic Ports range (49152-65535) have been
> specifically set aside for local and dynamic use and cannot be
> assigned through IANA.  Application software may simply use any
> dynamic port that is available on the local host, without any
> sort
> of assignment.  On the other hand, application software MUST NOT
> assume that a specific port number in the Dynamic Ports range
> will
> always be available for communication at all times, and a port
> number in that range hence MUST NOT be used as a service
> identifier.

The reserved ports:

> Ports in the User Ports range (1024-49151) are available for
> assignment through IANA, and MAY be used as service identifiers
> upon successful assignment.

> Ports in the System Ports range (0-1023) are also available for
> assignment through IANA.  Because the System Ports range is both
> the smallest and the most densely assigned, the requirements for
> new assignments are more strict than those for the User Ports
> range, and will only be granted under the "IETF Review" or "IESG
> Approval" procedures [RFC5226](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5226).

The introduction explains the confusion:

> For many years, the assignment of new service names and port number
> values for use with the Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) [RFC0793]
> and the User Datagram Protocol (UDP) [RFC0768] has had less than
> clear guidelines.

It seems that Windows XP is not following RFC6335, but Solaris 10 does.

Answer (score 1):

What voretaq7 said along with [this](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xml)
but being pedantic there is a technical requirement. Historically daemons/servers in *nix are running on ports < 1024 (calling them system ports) thus in order to avoid conflict, source ports (User ports) are > 1024 (or to be precise 1024 - 49151)
However that is not always the case as you say and it depends on the implementation.
All in all the above link gives a list of RFC's but probably the most specific one is
[RFC5226](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5226) which describes the "Expert Review" process of IANA.

Comment: Some NFS server implementations require that NFS client to use a port <1024. So technically it was always possible to use all ports as source port. What I am asking is for a document that ask to use for ports over 1024. It seems that actually the client should use ports over 49152.

Comment: That doesn't disprove my answer. See here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16564/why-are-the-first-1024-ports-restricted-to-the-root-user-only
Why is that the IANA assignment and RFC 6056 don't cover you?
After you can always give recomendations nobody stops you from implementing a web browser that will use port 80 as a source port

Comment: Being equally pedantic, there is no *requirement* that the privileged or "well-known" ports not be used as a source port (see Mircea's counterexample with privileged NFS ports) -- It's not commonly done for the reasons you mentioned, but it's also not forbidden.  AFAIK according to the TCP and UDP RFCs any unused port is fair game as a source port. The rules we make up on top of that are for our convenience :-)